# alignment according to the center in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

is there any way to center the text below each picture? I've hardcoded it for the homeworks but as you can see the length can vary! I'm using a Relative layout and the textView are Below each picture?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-implementing-a-dashboard-activity/

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of linear layouts you could achieve something like this

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="1.0" android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test" android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1.0" 
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"                   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test" android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="1.0" android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test" android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1.0" 
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"                   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test" android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I strongly recommend checking out the post I send as comment. It uses the dashboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLecture" android:src="@drawable/icon3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgMail" android:src="@drawable/icon4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_marginRight="60dp"></ImageView>
  <TextView android:text="Lectures" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:layout_below="@+id/imgLecture" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="60dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" ></TextView>
<TextView android:text="Mail" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:layout_below="@+id/imgMail" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="60dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" ></TextView>

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgExam" android:src="@drawable/icon5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView3" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgGrade" android:src="@drawable/icon6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_marginRight="60dp"></ImageView>
  <TextView android:text="Exams" android:id="@+id/textView5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:layout_below="@+id/imgExam" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="60dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" ></TextView>
<TextView android:text="Grades" android:id="@+id/textView6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:layout_below="@+id/imgGrade" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="60dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" ></TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

it was very hard to go through your xml file ...
why don't you use a gridview and for each view you can have an image an a text below... it's much easier this way...